# Problems with pandas and numpy where condition/multiple values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have the follwoing pandas dataframe:

```
A  B
1  3
0  3
1  2
0  1
0  0
1  4
....
0  0
```

I would like to add a new column at the right side, following the following condition:

If the value in `B` has `3` or `2` add `1` in the `new_col` for instance:

```
(*)
A  B new_col
1  3  1
0  3  1
1  2  1
0  1  0
0  0  0
1  4  0
....
0  0  0
```

So I tried the following:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['B'] == 3 & 2,'1','0')
```

However it did not worked:

```
A  B new_col
1  3  0
0  3  0
1  2  1
0  1  0
0  0  0
1  4  0
....
0  0  0
```

Any idea of how to do a multiple contidition statement with pandas and numpy like `(*)`?.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Pandas [isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) which will return a boolean showing whether the elements you're looking for are contained in column `'B'`.

```
df['new_col'] = df['B'].isin([3, 2])
   A  B new_col
0  1  3    True
1  0  3    True
2  1  2    True
3  0  1   False
4  0  0   False
5  1  4   False
```

Then, you can use [astype](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to convert the `boolean` values to `0` and `1`, `True` being `1` and `False` being `0`

```
df['new_col'] = df['B'].isin([3, 2]).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  new_col
0  1  3        1
1  0  3        1
2  1  2        1
3  0  1        0
4  0  0        0
5  1  4        0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I noted that you used `isin()`. Im just curious, what about ifinsted of `3`, `4`... Can I still use the `isin()` function?

Answer (score 2):

```
df['new_col'] = [1 if x in [2, 3] else 0 for x in df.B]
```

The operators `* + ^` work on booleans as expected, and mixing with integers give the expected result. So you can also do:

```
df['new_col'] = [(x in [2, 3]) * 1 for x in df.B]
```

Comment: Top one is same as my answer

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy`:

```
>>> df['new_col'] = np.where(np.logical_or(df['B'] == 3, df['B'] == 2), '1','0')
>>> df
   A  B new_col
0  1  3       1
1  0  3       1
2  1  2       1
3  0  1       0
4  0  0       0
5  1  4       0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,0,1,0,0,1],'B':[3,3,2,1,0,4]})
print df
df['C']=[1 if vals==2 or vals==3 else 0 for vals in df['B'] ]
print df

   A  B
0  1  3
1  0  3
2  1  2
3  0  1
4  0  0
5  1  4
   A  B  C
0  1  3  1
1  0  3  1
2  1  2  1
3  0  1  0
4  0  0  0
5  1  4  0
```

Comment: @piRSquared: I do not understand. What is expected? @ john doe: I do not understand your comment at all

Comment: @piRSquared thanks for pointing it out. I missed it completely but now I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

using numpy

```
df['new'] = (df.B.values[:, None] == np.array([2, 3])).any(1) * 1
```

---

#### Timing

***over given data set***

[image]

***over 60,000 rows***

[image]

Comment: It seems that this is the most efficient solution, thanks!.